# SAS how do I change value labels in sgplot

Tags: sas, label, boxplot

I have a problem with changing value labels of xaxis in proc sgplot (see graph). I want to change x value labels 0 to 'female' and 1 to 'male', what should I do?
Many thanks in advance!

[this is a box plot, label of x is gender, and I want the value labels displaying female instead of "0" and male instead of '1'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SGO1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the value before creating your GPLOT.
Following this example :
http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=graphref&docsetTarget=n0zqluxg8kkrign1t1t727dis8ea.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

First prepare your data :

```
data work.classtemp (drop=name );
   length Gender $ 6;
   set sashelp.class;
   if sex="F" then Gender="Female";
      else Gender="Male";
run;
proc sort data=work.classtemp out=work.class;
   by weight height;
run;
```

After, label defintion :

```
legend1 label=none value=("Male" "Female") Position=(right middle outside)
across=1;
legend2 label=none value=("Male" "Female");
```

In your case you have to prepare your data before the GPLOT by changing the 1 to Male and 0 to Female.

With something like this :

```
data want;
set mydata;
if value=0 then Gender="Female";
else Gender="Male";
run;
```

Regards

Comment: Don't forget to tick my answer as correct answer :) You're welcome